# Parallel command run in linux

Tags: scripts, parallels

I was using the following bash script to run multiple commands in parallel. It actually waits till all of the parallel commands get finished and then proceeds. Now, I want to change this bash in a way that waits only for the first "kill" and it does not matter that this kill comes from which command's execution. Any suggestion for doing that?

```
for cmd in "$@"; do {
  echo "Process \"$cmd\" started";
  $cmd & pid=$!
  PID_LIST+=" $pid";
} done

trap "kill $PID_LIST" SIGINT

echo "Parallel processes have started";

wait $PID_LIST

echo
echo "All processes have completed";
```

Comment: Any reason why not using GNU Parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect that a subprocess has ended by trapping the SIGCHLD signal.

Comment: You mean by substituting SIGINT with SIGCHLD and eliminating the wait $PID_LIST line?

Comment: The wait still has to be there or the script will run off the bottom. The CHLD signal will trigger the trap and interrupt the wait.